# hive and presto，Integer division truncation problem

Tags: sql, hive, presto

Why does the splitting of the two bigint type data in hive does not occur for integer division truncation, but occurs in presto

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presto mechanics:

1. Load data from various datasources via `connectors` into Presto JVM. (Hive connector, Mysql connector, etc. see [this](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector.html))
2. Processing(scalar functions or aggregate functions) the data using `Java` code.
3. Output the results from JVM (or disk if enable `spill`).

In Java `1/2=0` therefore Presto will be the same. In Hive, I think because of  UDF like `overrive operator`: [LanguageManual+UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ArithmeticOperators)

To avoid truncation, just need to 'Thinking in Java':

```
int a = 1
int b = 2
c = 1.0*a/b
```

In Presto SQL

```
-- result: 0.3333333333333333
select cast(1 as double) / 3 from table_name
```

see: [Migrating From Hive](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html#use-cast-when-dividing-integers)

Answer (score 6):

It also can be done this way.
select 1.0 * 1 / 3 from table_name Instead of casting the value